# Mapping Tab to Omicompletion in GVim

Tags: vim, autocomplete, mapping

Omnicompletion works pressing `<C-X><C-O>` making a dropdown list appear.
I wanted to map it as `<S-Tab> <C-X><C-O>` but first I wanted to test it as: `<C-F5> <C-X><C-O>.`
It does complete the word but the dropdown list doesn't show up. (the same happens with the plugin SuperTab).

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** **it Works** like this `inoremap <S-F5> <C-X><C-O>` but it doesn't work like this `inoremap <Tab> <C-X><C-O> or <TAB> <C-X><C-O>`

CODE:

```
" autocomplete using tab
imap <C-F5> <C-X><C-O>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One day, I found this (probably on vim.org):

```
fu! InsertTabWrapper(direction)
  let char_before = col('.') - 1
  if !char_before || getline('.')[char_before - 1] !~ '\k'
    return "\<tab>"
  elseif "backward" == a:direction
    return "\<c-p>"
  else
    return "\<c-n>"
  endif
endfu

inoremap <tab> <c-r>=InsertTabWrapper("forward")<cr>
inoremap <s-tab> <c-r>=InsertTabWrapper("backward")<cr>
```

And it works like a charm.

Comment: Strange, this is exactly what I want, but it doesn't work for me. Has no effect at all. Posted a separate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15643234/remapping-tab-completions-in-vim