# Remapping tab completions in vim

Tags: vim, tab-completion

I've got a crazy little challenge. I'd like to remap tab and shift + tab to the basic tab completions in vim. Here's where I started:

```
set completeopt=
inoremap <tab> <C-n>
inoremap <S-tab> <C-p>
```

That didn't have any effect at all, and I also realized it might be messing up my snippets plugin. I went googling around and found this: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Smart_mapping_for_tab_completion, but had little luck implementing any of the suggestions.

I'd like to map  to tab and  to shift + tab, without losing snippet functionality. Any help would rock!

**Update:** I also tried this with now luck. It had no perceivable effect.

```
fu! InsertTabWrapper(direction)
  let char_before = col('.') - 1
  if !char_before || getline('.')[char_before - 1] !~ '\k'
    return "\<tab>"
  elseif "backward" == a:direction
    return "\<c-p>"
  else
    return "\<c-n>"
  endif
endfu
inoremap <tab> <c-r>=InsertTabWrapper("forward")<cr>
inoremap <s-tab> <c-r>=InsertTabWrapper("backward")<cr>
```

Comment: say in a php/java/c file, you have "while it was called" in comments, and then you type `wh<tab>`, what you want to have? `while`? or `while loop snippet`?

Comment: while loop snippet. It's not a very common one for me, but I'd want the snippet to take priority.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you that mapping `<tab>` is a headache thing in vim.

Personally I have **SuperTab**, **Neocompletecache**, **Snipmate** and **pydiction**.... it really took some time to let them work together, with **`<tab>`**... even if not (maybe) perfect, it is enough for my daily usage.

Back to your problem, you could consider to install a plugin called `superTab` (https://github.com/ervandew/supertab) and in your `.vimrc` add these lines:

```
let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = 'context'
let g:SuperTabContextTextOmniPrecedence = ['&omnifunc','&completefunc']
let g:SuperTabRetainCompletionType=2

inoremap <expr><Enter>  pumvisible() ? "\<C-Y>" : "\<Enter>"
inoremap <expr><TAB>  pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" : "\<TAB>"
```

then .... good luck... I hope it works for your requirement.

Comment: Thanks, Kent! I looked at SuperTab. It's a ton of overhead for me, I don't have use for everything it does. Thanks, though!

Comment: @Costa I suggest first install it, and copy those lines in your vimrc, and do a test, better do tests on more than one file types. If it worked as you expected. Go through the help file, take a look why it worked and what can it do... To be honest, I just commented out my neocomp and pydict plugins, and also did some small changes on supertab setting. it **seems** worked, I just tested in vim ft and a java ft.  I feel that your problem could be solved without installing that superTab. But I didn't give it a try.. Good luck man!